# Ktor JWT authentication - redirect after authentication

Tags: authentication, jwt, ktor

I am following the Ktor tutorial (https://ktor.io/docs/jwt.html#jwt-settings) on authentication with JWT. I successfully create a token, **but am not sure how to redirect to another page when successfully logged in**. The code below fails with a 406.

This code is close to the tutorial:

```
  post("/login") {
        val formParameters = call.receiveParameters()
        val username = formParameters["username"]
        // validate user and password here later....
        val token = createMyToken(username)   // just create the token  works fine
        call.respond(mapOf("token" to token)) // this line fails with HTTP 406
    }
```

How do I redirect to another page such as the one configured below? Do I need to return the token as well?

```
  authenticate("auth-jwt") {
        get("/securPortal") {
            // show secure stuff here.....
        }
    }
```

My JWT config:

```
fun Application.configureJWTSecurity() {

authentication {
    jwt("auth-jwt") {
        realm = jwtRealm
        verifier(
            JWT
                .require(Algorithm.HMAC256(jwtSecret))
                .withAudience(jwtAudience)
                .withIssuer(jwtIssuer)
                .build()
        )
        validate { credential ->
            if (credential.payload.audience.contains(jwtAudience)) JWTPrincipal(credential.payload) else null
        }
        // if authentication fails
        challenge { defaultScheme, realm ->
            call.respond(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, "Token is not valid or has expired")
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: It's assumed that the client makes a `POST /login` request, retrieves the token, and then requests protected resources by sending the token in the `Authorization` header. Unfortunately, you cannot achieve that by redirecting the client.